# Factorization of a closed shell Slater determinant into spatial and spin part

Tags: reference-request, hartree-fock

I'm studying the HF method, so I have a non-relativistic time-independent Hamiltonian.

Since in the Hamiltonian, there is no spin, we have:

$$
\left[\hat{H}, \hat{S}_z \right] = 0 \quad \text{and} \quad \left[\hat{H}, \hat{S}^2 \right] = 0
$$

This means that it should be possible to factorize the total wave function as:

$$
\Psi(1,2, \dots)=\underbrace{\Phi(1,2,\dots)}_{\text{Spatial part}}\underbrace{\chi(1,2,\dots)}_{\text{Spin part}}
$$

From Szabo, Modern Quantum Chemistry, chapter 2.5.2, I read that closed shell Slater determinants are eigenfunctions of $\hat{S}_z$ and $\hat{S}^2$.
So a closed shell Slater determinant should be factorizable into spatial and spin parts as above. Is this correct?
I know the question sounds obvious, but I want to make sure I understood correctly.

Comment: Kindly check this [link](https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Pacific_Union_College/Quantum_Chemistry/08%3A_Multielectron_Atoms/8.06%3A_Antisymmetric_Wavefunctions_can_be_Represented_by_Slater_Determinants) You will see that the determinant can be factored out as spatial and spin components.

Comment: I remember that such factorization can be done only for one- and two-electron systems. It is generally not possible for a system with >2 electrons.

Comment: @jxzou I'm now studying "Spin Eigenfunction, construction and use" by Ruben Pauncz. I will understand the topic in detail and then maybe leave the answer here. I want to clarify this because I think it's of central relevance. In fact, I think this is strictly related to spin contamination.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but are you able write an answer now? If so, please do not do it in a comment like you did last time.

Comment: @NikeDattani Unfortunately to this, I'm not able to answer yet :(. I'm very sorry ... This is more complicated than expected. I can tell you that you have to look for Configuration State Functions (CSFs). But I still need to study the topic in detail.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/623695/134583 ?